# Reset All Unique Permissions to inherit Parent

Tags: powershell, permissions

I have just Migrated our SharePoint to O365 2013 and all the permissions seem to be messing up. I need to reset all the permissions to inherit from its parent. I have tried this script to no prevail.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Variable for Web URL
$WebURL ="https://Bytescloud.sharepoint.com/"

#get Web object
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

#Get Lists with Unique permissions - Exclude Hidden lists
$ListColl =  $web.lists | Where-Object  { ($_.hidden -eq $false) }
#Enumerate through each list and reset permission inheritance  
foreach($list in $ListColl)
{
 #Reset list inheritance
 $list.ResetRoleInheritance()
 Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on List:" $list.Title

 $items = $list.Items | Where-Object{$_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments};
 foreach($item in $items)
 {
  #Reset broken list item inheritance
  $item.ResetRoleInheritance()
  Write-host "Broken Inheritance Reset on List Item:" $item.URL
 }
 #}
$folders = $list.Folders
if ($folders.Count -gt 0)
{
 foreach ($folder in $folders) 
 {
  if ($folder.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
  {
    $folder.ResetRoleInheritance()
    $folder.update()
  }
 }
}
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog helpful for the commands to reset permissions inheritance, as it mentions doing the the $web.update both before and after the $web.ReserRoleInheritance() command.  Not sure why needed but doing both before and after worked for me:

http://scriptingsamurai.com/sharepoint-permissions-management/

Answer (score 0):

You should use SharePoint client libraries to access a SharePoint site in Office 365. Please have a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started. After installing the SharePoint Online Management shell you should be able to connect to a SharePoint online site with "Get-SPOSite". [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn568040.aspx) is also a example of how to work with groups and users.